# orgmode - disable elisp code execute confirmation dialog

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I have below code to call elisp function "myfun" when user click the link:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output raw
  (defun myfun(filepath lineno)
    (if (not (get-buffer bufname))
        (get-buffer-create bufname)
      )
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window bufname)
    (global-linum-mode)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert-file-contents (format "%s" filepath))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line lineno)
    (setq start (point))
    (forward-line -1)
    (setq end (point))
    (let ((x (make-overlay start end)))
      (overlay-put x 'face '(:background "#fef0f1")))
    )

  (defun createSampleFile(file-name count)
    (let ((c 0))
      (with-temp-buffer
        (while (< c (* 2 count))
          (setq c (1+ c))
          (insert (format "line %d\n" c))
          (write-file filename)
          ))))

  (let ((c 0)(filename nil))
    (while (< c 4)
      (setq c (1+ c))
      (setq filename (format "./test%d.txt" c))
      (createSampleFile filename c)
      (princ (format "[[elisp:(myfun '%s' %d)][%s]]\n" filename c filename))
      ))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[elisp:(myfun './test1.txt' 1)][./test1.txt]]
[[elisp:(myfun './test2.txt' 2)][./test2.txt]]
[[elisp:(myfun './test3.txt' 3)][./test3.txt]]
[[elisp:(myfun './test4.txt' 4)][./test4.txt]]
```

But when click the link, I got below prompt warning dialog always:
[image]

Can we disable that dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add below line to init.el:

```
(setq org-confirm-elisp-link-function nil)
```

Comment: ... but heed the warning in the doc of the variable. Executing arbitrary code (in elisp or in any language) is risky.

Comment: Maybe it's more better to add it to org file only but don't add it in init.el.

Comment: Yes - at least, you can look at the code and make sure it does not contain hidden bombs, before marking it as above. That can be done with a [file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables). And you don't give blanket permission to any file to execute any code.

Comment: @Nick Do you think org-confirm-babel-evaluate is the same as this case. I usually set it to nill in init.el. babel code need user run it I think, will that automatically executed when open a file?

Comment: As NickD mentions, a safer alternative is to add this as the first line of your file:  `# -*- mode: Org; org-confirm-elisp-link-function: nil; -*-`